# Как произносить Ютуб - с мягким ''т" или твердым?

Tags: фонетика, орфоэпия

Часто слышу, что русские произносят это слово с мягким "т". Хотя, если строго следовать правилам, здесь должен быть твердый согласный. Но все же, как правильно? Как вы произносите, коллеги?